# Matching Zip Codes with various formatting

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a few tables I'm trying to combine on the zip code field.

My problem is that the zip codes are in no consistent format at all.

I've been spending a lot of time trying to clean the data, and I was wondering if this is a problem others have already worked on.

Here is the formula I have thus far.

`=VALUE(LEFT(TRIM(TEXT(LEFT(O2,5),"0")),FIND("-",O2&"-",1)-1))`

Then I changed the format of the column to Special > Zip Codes.  But I can't get it to match the other column for some unknown reason.

EDIT:
The location of the zip codes is United States.  They come in any of the following formats, where # is a number in [0,9] (one of my problems is that the formats aren't consistent.:

```
#####
#####-####
#########
```

Comment: `> format of the column` is a display format, that might differ from the actual content of the cell, as in an intger number that can be formatted as in e.g. `=text(12345,"0-00")`. A comparing op will use the unformatted content.

Comment: What is the format of the Zip codes? Are they digit only (US), or numbers and letters in various places (UK) or fixed positions for numbers and letters (Dutch)?

Comment: Sorry, I'll add more context about the location.

Comment: Inconsistent format is or may be mitigated by/with the help of my method below.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>F8</kbd>
Click <kbd>New</kbd> and it should bring up the code editor, paste this

```
function stripToInteger(s as string)
  nums="0123456789"
  stripToInteger=""
  for i=1 to len(s)
    if instr(1,nums,mid(s,i,1))>0 then
      stripToInteger=stripToInteger+mid(s,i,1)
    endif
  next
end function
```

The use it like 
`=STRIPTOINTEGER("oi123oi12po3i")`
which should display `123123` (it does in my LibreOffice ;-p).

Then use `TEXT(reference,"000-0000")` or similar to display it in a nice format.